# Make it so the user has to scroll in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have an application that is running on the iPhone that has a UIWebView on it. I load a webpage into this view and the user can continue to the next page by pressing buttons that I have added to a UIToolBar at the bottom of the page. What I am after is to stop the user from pressing these buttons until they have scrolled half way or all the way down the page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's going to be half way down the page and further then you could probably use the content offset of the scroll view of the webview.

I would create an instance variable in your controller that references the scrollview of the webview.  In iOS 5 you can use the webview.scrollView property to access the scrollView but in previous versions you would have to search the subviews of the webView.

```
if([_webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
  _webViewScrollView = _webView.scrollView;
}
else {
  for (UIView *subview in _webView.subviews) {          
    if ([subview isKindOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
      _webViewScrollView = subview;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I would set the scrollviews delegate to be the controller I'm interested in

```
_webViewScrollView.delegate = self;
```

and implement the following delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  if( scrollView.contentOffset.y > someValue ) {
    // Enable Buttons
  }
  else {
    // Make / Keep buttons inactive..
  }
}
```

An alternative method would be to use some javascript and do some funky stuff with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Answer (score 1):

use `scrollView` property of UIWebView and use its delegation call back

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset 
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

to handle the scrolling end event and UIScrollview property contentOffset can tell u that the scroll position with respect to its content size(actual size of ur webpage).

Answer (score 0):

At the launch of application make your toolbar button disable. Then check for current scroll position by adding this line.

```
int position = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,180);"];
```

Once you scrolled your page to above specific position make your toolbar button enabled.
**OR**
You can use scroll view delegate methods.